# Not "Sequential Convoy" pattern, but another pattern?

Tags: message-queue, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues, enterprise-integration

The Sequential Convoy pattern defines that you can have 1 or more sets of queued messages and within each set of messages, the order of the messages is respected when they're processed.

I'm looking for a similar pattern, but I would like to order the sets and am unconcerned with the order of processing within each set.

For example, set A might have items 1, 2, and 3; set B has items a, b, and c. I don't care what order 1, 2, and 3 are processed in, nor am I concerned about the order of a, b, and c. However, I want to guarantee that all of set A is complete before set B begins.

Questions:

- Is there a name for this pattern?
- Is there a way to enable it in Azure Service Bus Queue / Azure Logic Apps?

Comment: Are the sets A and B being fed to the same workflow for processing? Can you please elaborate the business requirement?

Comment: Yes, sets A and B are being fed to the same workflow. 

We know all items, like product items, say phones, in batch A are unique and the same with batch B. However, some items between A and B batches can be the same, like the iPhone11. But we know that changes in the source system for batch A always happen before changes in batch B. So I don't want to update a price for batch A.[iPhone11] after price changes made for batch B.[iPhone11].